# Is there a way to encode spaces inside a Tcl string?

Tags: tcl

There is a third party software that linked with Tcl library and is parsing given tcl script.
One if it's commands takes a file name or list of file names. When there are spaces in file name/path it chokes... considers it a list of names, even if I enclose it in curly braces or double quotes.

Can a string/path (spaces within) be encode in a way that other Tcl commands will still interpret it correctly?

Comment: You could try a backslash, or multiple backslashes (`abc\\ 123`) within the filenames.  That might do the trick.  It's going to be hard to figure out how many backslashes to use.  But ultimately, you should get the maintainer of the third party library to fix their package.    Even if you get their API to accept it as a single filename, there's no guarantee that their other internal procedures will handle it correctly.

Comment: Another possibility is to rename your file, use the API, then rename your file back to the original.   I do this with one utility that cannot handle unicode filenames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following are the standard escape sequences for a space in Tcl:

- “`\` ” — a backslash followed by a space.
- “`\040`” — a backslash followed by a `0` and the *octal* for 32.
- “`\x20`” — a backslash followed by a `x` and the *two-digit hexadecimal* for 32. (Only really suitable if the character following is not a hex digit because of a bug in many versions of Tcl.)
- “`\u0020`” — a backslash followed by a `u` and the *four-digit hexadecimal* for 32.
- “`\U000020`” — a backslash followed by a `U` and the *six-digit hexadecimal* for 32. (Introduced in Tcl 8.6 as part of migration path to supporting newer Unicode characters.)

One of those might work in your situation. Or might if you quote the backslash with another backslash enough times; you're effectively playing “guess how badly wrong someone's software is” at this point. (It sounds like stuff is going through an ill-advised `eval` somewhere. Maybe several times. Maybe different amounts on different code paths. That's *awful* if it is true…)